# Script for Business Objects user administration

Tags: business-objects

I have a list of users maintained by an external source and need to synchronize local users in Business Objects with this list (or at least add any new users) on a daily basis.

The only way I can find to do this in BO is to create a csv-file and import it manually through the interface. Is there a way to automate this with a script?

We have Business Objects 4.2 SP3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can certainly create a program to synchronize users.  See the [BusinessObjects Java Developers Guide](http://help.sap.com/businessobject/product_guides/sbo41/en/sbo41_bip_java_dg_en.zip) for information on creating users.

Comment: Thanks, that opens up a lot of possibilities!